# Service Workers with Python Requests

Tags: python, service-worker

I currently made a self tool to post tweets on my twitter profile etc. Since yesterday twitter added service workers to their site and now i cant use my tool anymore. It seems it has to do with python requests and the service workers, from what I found on google is that service workers are built in to the browser (so I came to my own conclusion that a requests library doesn't have this built in). So my question is, is there maybe a way to replicate the browser behaviour with python requests library? Or what changes with a python requests library when a site adds service workers? Is there anything that changes?